# Expresion regular obtener solo una parte de la cadena

Tags: regex

Tengo la siguiente cadena de caracteres:

ACAABAACAAABACDBADDDFSDDDFFSSSASDAFAAACBAAAFASD

Como puedo buscar todos los caracteres (distintos de A) seguidos de triple A, es decir, tienen AAA a la derecha. Sin incluir la triple A en la salida, solo incluyendo el carácter inmediatamente anterior a AAA.

Comment: Esta pregunta tiene varios problemas. A) En qué lenguaje? B) Ese es el enunciado de tu problema, pero no sabemos cuál es tu pregunta. ¿Cuál es tu pregunta? C) No sabemos si es un problema relacionado con la programación porque no hay lenguaje ni código en la pregunta. Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.

Comment: @Alfabravo no hay que ser tan duro, facilmente se puede entender que el sujeto que realizo la pregunta lo unico que necesita es una expresion regular sin importar el lenguaje ya que las regex funcionan de manera similar en cualquier lenguaje.

Comment: @AgileSoul significa que el ejemplo mínimo podría haberlo hecho en cualquier lenguaje, también. Ese miedo a probar, que a veces se puede ver como pereza, es inexcusable. El código no se va a caer como un puente, se puede probar siempre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta expresión te podría valer:

```
[^A](?=AAA)
```

Básicamente lo que hace `[^A]` es reconocer un caracter distinto de `A` seguido de `AAA` sin incluir esto último en la captura.

Puedes probarla aquí: https://regex101.com/r/Iu3F6T/1